# Applying function to multiple objects

Tags: javascript

I have the following code below:

```
this.resize2.intrface.transform(Raphael.format("t{0},{1},S{2},{3},{4},{5}{6}",
                                    this.resize2.intrface.ox,
                                    this.resize2.intrface.oy,                                                
                                    xmove,    
                                    ymove,
                                    this.resize2.bbx,
                                    this.resize2.bby,
                                    this.resize2.intrface.scale));
this.resize2.core.transform(Raphael.format("t{0},{1},S{2},{3},{4},{5}{6}",
                                    this.resize2.intrface.ox,
                                    this.resize2.intrface.oy,                                                
                                    xmove,    
                                    ymove,
                                    this.resize2.bbx,
                                    this.resize2.bby,
                                    this.resize2.intrface.scale));
```

I would like to apply the transform function to both object in one line. Is this possible? To give an idea what I intend to do see the following (not working) example below:

```
$(this.resize2.intrface, this.resize2.core).transform(Raphael.format("t{0},{1},S{2},{3},{4},{5}{6}",
                                    this.resize2.intrface.ox,
                                    this.resize2.intrface.oy,                                                
                                    xmove,    
                                    ymove,
                                    this.resize2.bbx,
                                    this.resize2.bby,
                                    this.resize2.intrface.scale));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Should that be `$(this.resize2.intrface, this.resize2.core)`?

Comment: That's correct. I have edited the code. (this is not the reason it is not working by the way)

Answer (score 0):

This is about a bit of duplicate code refactoring.

```
function transform(factoryMethod) {
    factoryMethod(Raphael.format("t{0},{1},S{2},{3},{4},{5}{6}",
                    this.resize2.intrface.ox,
                    this.resize2.intrface.oy,
                    xmove,    
                    ymove,
                    this.resize2.bbx,
                    this.resize2.bby,
                    this.resize2.intrface.scale));
}
```

Use this to invoke:

```
transform.apply(this, [this.resize2.intrface.transform]);
transform.apply(this, [this.resize2.core.transform]);
```

Comment: This gives the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transform' of undefined raphael-min.js:8
a._extractTransform       raphael-min.js:8
A.transform               raphael-min.js:8
transform                 Index:224
mover2                    Index:233
k                         raphael-min.js:8
bY                        raphael-min.js:8
f